# Excel Formula in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am trying to insert the following formula using vba:

```
Cells(i, 17).Formula = "=IF(""" & Range("M" & i).value & """ = """","""",IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$D:$D,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("M" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$C:$C,0)),"""")"
```

For some reason i get an application undefined error. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: `Debug.Print` the formula you are using to check for errors.

Comment: If you are trying to use `MATCH("*abc*", ...` you do not have to make it look like `MATCH("*" & "abc" & "*", ...` . See my response to your last question.

Comment: Go to Excel. Write the formula there. Select it. Then in the immediate window write `?Selection.Formula`. See the result. Start from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `)`

```
Cells(i, 17).Formula = "=IF(""" & Range("M" & i).value & """ = """","""",IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$D:$D,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("M" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$C:$C,0)),""""))"
```